# Avoid hardcoding enum type

Tags: c++, c++11

In `c++11` code it would be nice to avoid mentioning a specific enum qualifier every time I use the enum value - as it is a new code and it is refactored a lot.

For that purpose is it possible something in the spirit of the last line of this pseudo code:

```
enum abc { a,b,c };
// some long code of events which returns the enum's value
auto e = []()->abc{return abc::b;}();
if (e == std::declval(e)::a) { ...
```

If not possible in `C++11` will it become possible in `C++14` or 17?

Comment: You don't have to use the enum's name unless it's an `enum class`. You can simply use `if (e == a)`

Comment: Missing `class` turned out to be the bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're close, you can use `decltype`:

```
if (e == decltype(e)::a) {
    ...
```

Comment: What am I missing here, why doesn't just plain `a` work?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe in this case, it will.  But if the enum is declared in a namespace, or is a class member or is an enum class, it will break.

Comment: Awesome! Also missing class in the enum definition was a bug, I am glad I asked this question.